# Fluid layout with optional sideboxes

Tags: html, css

I want a layout with three boxes (two optional) like this:

[side box 1] [ main content

[side box 2]  . main content ]

or

[ main content spans 100% if side boxes aren't provided ]

I want the main content box to span the entire height and width available in `#load` (minus margins) except if the side boxes are there, then I want it to only span up until those boxes (and their right margin).

My CSS:

```
#load {
    margin: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 1080px;
}
#primary,#secondaryOne,#secondaryTwo {
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#primary {
    float: right;
    height: inherit;
    width: 75%;
    height:500px;
    background:red;
}
#secondaryOne,#secondaryTwo {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 300px;
    height: 220px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 20%;
    clear:left;
    float:left;
}
#secondaryTwo {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Simple HTML

```
<div id='load'>
    <div id='primary'></div>
    <div id='secondaryOne'></div>
    <div id='secondaryTwo'></div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4cvv/56/)

### Problems

1. **SOLVED**Making #primary span the entire width if the sideboxes are missing.
2. **SOLVED**Is there a way to line the two sideboxes (#secondaryOne,#secondaryTwo) on the left side of #primary without nesting them in a separate div?  If I use float: left on them, they line side by side, if I don't float them, the #primary generates below them, not beside them.

### Solutions

1. Problem #1 was solved by joeytje50 using the secondary + primary tags and placing the secondary side boxes before the primary in HTML.
2. Problem #2 was solved in more than one way.  The way I chose so that the secondary tags were placed together and before the primary was by NoobEditor using `clear: left` and a negative `margin-top`.

The solution can be found at: http://jsfiddle.net/v4cvv/67/

The main part of the solution is:

```
#primary {
    width: 100%;
}
#secondaryOne + #primary, #secondaryTwo + #primary {
    margin-top: -221px;
    width: 75%;
}
```

### Alternate Solution

One problem I found with the above solution, is it requires the two boxes and them to be the same height.  A solution around this is by grouping the boxes in their own div.  This solution is:

**HTML**

```
<div id='load'>
    <div id="sideboxes">
        <div id="boxOne" class="box"></div>
        <div id="boxTwo" class="box"></div>
        <div id="boxThree" class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="primary" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
#primary {
    float: right;
    display:block;
    height: 97%;
    width: 100%;
}
#sideboxes + #primary {
    width: 75%;
}
#sideboxes {
    float: left;
    height: 97%;
    width: 23%;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#sideboxes .box {
    float: left;
    height: 220px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The alternate solution no longer requires clear and can be extended for other uses.  You may now also have 1, 2, 3, or however many boxes you want in the sideboxes div.

Thanks all for their help.

Comment: did you try float all to left? Floating only primary make the others stay below, on same space

Comment: Thanks for the advice, however, if I float left on all of them, then it shows up with the two sideboxes on top and the primary below them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question about the primary box being 100% width when the secondary boxes are not there, you could do the following:

```
#primary {width:100%;}
.secondary + #primary {width:75%;}
```

If you put that CSS code at the bottom of your stylesheet, and then put the primary div tag *after* your first secondary div tag, then it'll by default be 100% wide, unless there's an element that has `class="secondary"`. This won't change anything about the position the div is rendered, but it will fix your problem.

Alternatively, if your secondary divs are possibly hidden instead of not being there, you could do this:

```
#primary, .secondary.hidden + #primary {width:100%;}
.secondary + #primary {width:75%;}
```

That is, assuming you hide the secondary tabs via a class such as `.hidden`.

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/v4cvv/64/)** is a working version that becomes 100% width when the secondaries are removed, but still is 75% width when there is a `.secondary` element before it.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using a  combination of yours and NoobEditor's negative margin-top so I could keep the two sideboxes together in HTML.  I will post an update with my final code for others to see.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem #1

To get your `#primary` div to adapt it's width, you can use jquery to verify the presence of the `.secondary` divs and to set the an other width to the `#primary` div.

**[With `.secondary` demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v4cvv/28/)**

**[without `.secondary` demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v4cvv/39/)**

JQUERY:

```
if ($('.secondary').length){
    $('#primary').css('width', '75%');  
}
```

### Problem #2

You can use `clear:left;` and by changing the order of the `divs` in your html markup you will have your 2 divs stacked on the left and your content div on the right.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v4cvv/13/)**

HTML:

```
<div id='load'>
    <div id='primary'></div>
    <div id='secondaryOne' class="secondary"></div>
    <div id='secondaryTwo' class="secondary"></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.secondary{
    clear:left;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: you changed the order of the divs!!

Comment: I had to so nesting the 2 sideboxes isn't necessary

Comment: Okay, so the `clear: left` and the order of the sideboxes seems to fix problem #2.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it looks like JS may be the only way.  I'll accept this if I don't receive any CSS method.

Comment: I did upvote this (but someone downvoted) and your method for #2 seems the cleanest, but for solving #1 and #2 together I ended up using a different solution.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping your HTML markup smae, here is the solution for your problem :  [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v4cvv/17/)

**CSS**

```
html.body {
    height:100%;
}
#load {
    margin: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

#primary, #secondaryOne, #secondaryTwo {
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#primary {
    float: right;
    display:block;
    height: 100%;
    max-width:100%;;
    width: 68%;
    margin-top:-70%; /* this is the key */
}
#secondaryOne, #secondaryTwo {
    width:30%;
    height: 220px;
    margin-right: 10px;

}
#secondaryTwo {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for attempting an answer with the same HTML.  I can change the HTML, so it isn't much of an issue.  The margin-top seems a bit dirty and seems to cause issues when the sideboxes don't exist.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
#primary {
   min-width:75%;
   max-width:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Paramasivan/v4cvv/65/

Comment: I did try this, but even without the sideboxes, the width stays at 75% unless I am doing something wrong.